# Доступ к локальным переменным из функции

Tags: html, переменные, javascript, функции

Есть две функции. В первой функции определяются 2 переменные и передаются в качестве параметров второй функции. Эти 2 переменные будут использоваться в дальнейшем во второй функции. Первая функция вызывается по загрузке страницы. Проблема в том, что для того чтобы передать параметры второй функции эту вторую функцию необходимо вызвать. Это потянет за собой выполнение других инструкций определенных во второй функции что нежелательно. Есть ли какое то решение этой проблемы без использование глобальных переменных?

HTML:

```
<a href=''onclick='_default();return false;'>Link</a>
<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function _default() {

    var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var h = x.offsetHeight;

    _main(x, h);

}

_default();

function _main(x, h) {

    alert(x);
    alert(h);

}
```

Из кода видно что функция `_default()` выполняется по загрузке страницы и передает 2 переменные в качестве параметров функции `_main()` и соответственно запускает эту функцию. В результате по загрузке страницы видим два последовательных алерта. Как сделать так чтобы эти два окна появлялись по клику на ссылку (см. html код выше)?

Comment: Какая проблема? Не понятно что именно явилось проблемой.

Comment: по делу ничего нехочу говорить, но чейто минус поддерживаю...

Answer (score 1):

Объяви вторую функцию в первой. Так локальные переменные первой функции будут доступны в области видимости второй.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var h = x.offsetHeight;
    window.my_click = function(){
        alert(x);
        alert(h);
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="my_click()">Link</a>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/KiTE/wvb4Q/)

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем задавать такой вопрос, стоило получше разобраться с тем, что такое локальные переменные, и что такое глобальные. Локальная переменная существует только в том блоке кода, где была определена. В вашем случае - это метод `_default()`. В функцию `_main()` передаются значения этих переменных. Ваша задача заключается в том, как я понимаю, что надо при загрузке страницы определить X-координату некого блока div и его высоту. А только потом уже, при клике на ссылку, обрабатывать некий код на основе полученных в функции `_default()` данных. В этом случае вполне подошли бы глобальные переменные( не знаю, чем они вам не угодили ).Но, так как "желательно без них", то это можно сделать, например так( без лишнего вызова _default()):

```
<a href=''onclick='_default();return false;'>Link</a>
<div id='mydiv'></div>
<script>

function _default() {

    var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var h = x.offsetHeight;
    _main(x, h);

}

function _main(x, h) {

    alert(x);
    alert(h);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Asen

Ваши рекомендации принял к сведению.
Я убрал лишний вызов функции default(). А как мне теперь сделать так чтобы по клику на линк вызывалась функция _main()?

Comment: Дык, она она и так вызывается, только через функцию _default().

Comment: мне нужно чтобы в функции _default определялся набор переменных к которым я буду иметь доступ из функции _main (в этой функции я буду менять их значения). А функция _main чтобы запускалась по клику на линк

Comment: Так вы вместо 

    onclick='_default();return false;' 
   
напишите

    onclick='_main();return false;'

Comment: @Rules, что? А как же я тогда получу вот эти данные:

      var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var h = x.offsetHeight;

?

Comment: Ну это уже дело @olsen он спросил я ответил

Answer (score 0):

```
onload="void()"
...
<a href=''onclick='main();return false;'>Link</a>
<div id='mydiv'></div>

function _main() 
{
 var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
 var h = x.offsetHeight;
    alert(x);
    alert(h);
}
```

Зачем нам _default? Нам _default не нужен!